# SQL query - avoiding use of joins

Tags: postgresql, database-design

Consider the following SQL database:

[image]

I have two questions that I'm struggling on. I'm not really sure where to start.

1. Select the third largest salary from all the employees. No joins allowed.
2. Select salaries for all employees with their supervisor’s supervisor that has a salary NOT minimum out of all supervisor salaries. The query MUST use the "ANY" operator.

For the first one, how would I do it if I can't use any joins? I'm assuming I can't just simply use the MAX() function, so I would have to make one myself. I don't know how without using any joins.

For the second one, I'm guessing I would have to join a table to itself?

Comment: Define join please. Is a subselect a join (I would say it is, even if it doesn't use the word join)? What about `exists/not exists`?

Answer (score 1):

Just to tack on to this, depending on the question,  you may want to use DENSE_RANK, not ROW_NUMBER

```
SELECT lastname, firstname, id, salary 
FROM (SELECT DENSE_RANK(Salary) OVER (ORDER BY Salary DESC)  as pos, lastname, firstname, id, salary
      FROM employee
     ) tmp
WHERE pos = 3;
```

...because if you have two people with the same salary at position 3, you're going to miss one of them and that's a no no, similarly,  there may be multiple people with the same salaries at positions 1 and 2, so it's important to know what you are trying to obtain. Rank and Row number combined helps with disambiguation but you don't want to be arbitrary on matches.

Answer (score 0):

Subselects. Both.

```
Select salary
from employee
where 2 = (select count(1)
           from employee as bigersalary
           where bigersalary.salary > employee.salary)
```

The second is subselect in select part. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, I can see two possible solutions:

1. Use `ORDER BY` in a subquery with `LIMIT`:

   ```
   SELECT lastname, firstname, id, salary
     FROM (SELECT lastname, firstname, id, salary 
             FROM employee
            ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 3) tmp 
    ORDER BY salary LIMIT 1;
   ```
2. Use `ROW_NUMBER` to determine the position of every salary so you can return one or many results:

   ```
   SELECT lastname, firstname, id, salary
     FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) as pos, lastname, firstname, id, salary
             FROM employee
            ORDER BY pos) tmp
    WHERE pos = 3;
   ```

   If you need to return the 3rd, 4th, and 8th highest salaries, replace `WHERE pos = 3` with `WHERE pos IN (3, 4, 8)`. This would be suboptimal for very large tables, though.

For the second question, I'm not quite following the "has a salary NOT minimum out of all supervisor salaries" bit. Is it a single value that is being looked for? If so, an `ANY` with a subquery seems like an inefficient means to find the answer ...